# Python DEAP, why the genealogy history plot doesn't match the number of generations I set in my code?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

[Click here to see the genealogy tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ERxP.png)

This history shows 6 generations, but I set **ngen** to be 3. Why don't they match?

my code:

```
    result, log = algorithms.eaSimple(population, toolbox,cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.2,ngen=3, verbose=True,stats=fit_stats,halloffame = hof)
```

Another question is that each child should come from two ancestors, right? Why in this picture, they only originated from 1 ancestor?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show more code of your work?

Comment: Hi, I'm refering to this code: https://gist.github.com/fmder/5505431, if you run it, you will find that they don't match.